# PHP Array of Custom Class

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a custom class and have an array of those objects and I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is my code:

```
class NavigationItem
{


private $_filename;
private $_linkname;

public function __construct($filename, $linkname)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_filename = $filename;
    $this->_linkname = $linkname;
}

public function getFilename()
{
    return $_filename;  
}

public function getLinkname()
{
    return $_linkname;  
}
}

$navInfo = array();

$size = array_push($navInfo, new NavigationItem("index.php","HOME"),
                                  new NavigationItem("about.php","ABOUT"),
                                  new NavigationItem("coaches.php","STAFF"),
                                  new NavigationItem("summer.php","SUMMER 2011"),
                                  new NavigationItem("fall.php","FALL 2011"),
                                  new NavigationItem("history.php","HISTORY"),
                                  new NavigationItem("contact.php","CONTACT"));

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan=\"7\" height=\"125px\"><img src=\"images/banner_blue_skinny.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";

for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{
echo "<td class=\"linkCell\"><a class=\"navigation\" href=\"" . $navInfo[$i]->getFilename() . "\">" . $navInfo[$i]->getLinkname() . "</a></td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan=\"7\" class=\"gapCell\"></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

echo "";
echo "";

Any ideas?

Comment: What parent class are you trying to `parent::__construct();`? You don't inherit from one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$this` is used to denote object of class inside the method of class and should be used to access the properties and to call methods inside other method of same class.

```
public function getFilename()
{
    return $this->_filename;  
}
```

Remove the call of parent construct from constructor of your class since it is not inheriting from any other class

```
//parent::__construct();
```

Comment: Don't comment the `parent::__construct();` as suggested in the answer, you should delete the line. Commenting code out is a bad habit.

Comment: @matt: you did not get me what I said `Remove the call of...` and I just showed him by commenting it

Answer (score 5):

```
class NavigationItem
{

    private $_filename;
    private $_linkname;

    public function __construct($filename, $linkname)
    {
        $this->_filename = $filename;
        $this->_linkname = $linkname;
    }

    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->_filename;  
    }

    public function getLinkname()
    {
        return $this->_linkname;  
    }
}
```

**To access a class property, you must use `$this->` (not like in Java for example).**

For better readeability, you can indent your code. `parent::__construct()` was useless too, because you don't inherit from another class.

Now for the array usage, just a couple of tricks that (IMO) make it more readable :

```
$navInfo = array(
    new NavigationItem("index.php","HOME"),
    new NavigationItem("about.php","ABOUT"),
    new NavigationItem("coaches.php","STAFF"),
    new NavigationItem("summer.php","SUMMER 2011"),
    new NavigationItem("fall.php","FALL 2011"),
    new NavigationItem("history.php","HISTORY"),
    new NavigationItem("contact.php","CONTACT")
);

foreach ($navInfo as $item) {
    echo $item->getFilename() . "..." . $item->getLinkname();
}
```

With `foreach`, you don't need to know the size of the array, you just iterate through *each* item (you don't care about the index of the items).